repo tool: How to remove a project from a submanifest
Is it possible to remove a project from a repo tool submanifest?
This is my toplevel manifest.xml, that includes a submanifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="./" name="project1" />
  
  <!-- specify remote for linux base system -->
  <remote fetch="ssh://git@gitlab.com:10022/project2" name="baseSystem" />
  
  <default remote="project1" sync-j="4"/>
  
  <!-- include the base system manifest and apply changes to it later on in this manifest -->
  <submanifest name="baseSystem_manifest" remote="baseSystem" project="manifests" manifest-name="test_release.xml" revision="rev1" />
    
  <!-- remove all unwanted projects -->
  <remove-project name="android/projectXYZ" />
  
</manifest>

When I call repo sync --no-clone-bundle -c --no-tags -j4
I get an error
remove-project element specifies non-existent project: <remove-project name="android/projectXYZ"/>

android/projectXYZ is the name of the project in the submanifest.xml
I would like to include a submanifest from a different gitlab project and remove projects that are not relevant for my target project.
I'm using repo v2.45
